# Conky: write error: Bad file descriptor

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, conky

I just switched from Debian 9 to Ubuntu 18.04 (don't judge me).

I had a working Conky (don't judge me again) script on Debian 9 which does not run any more on Ubuntu 18.04 with the latest Conky version (1.10.9).

The problem is that every single custom command results in the following error:

```
write error: Bad file descriptor
```

It happens on simple commands such as a simple `cat` on a file.
However these commands work perfectly in my terminal, but I keep getting these `cat: write error: Bad file descriptor`, or `cut: write error: Bad file descriptor` or whatever depending on the command.
So I guess there is something going wrong when catching the output of the command, but what can it be? I just can't find any clue.

Answer (score 0):

Use strace command: `strace is a powerful command line tool for debugging and trouble shooting programs in Unix-like operating systems such as Linux. It captures and records all system calls made by a process and the signals received by the process`

```
$ strace cat test
```

Comment: The initial command is working, I think the problem is when conky tries to get the output. Therefore using strace shows no error.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois can you please try `strace echo "Some text here." > myfile.txt`?